# Build a new project in meteor, an error when inserting into mongoDB

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to `meteor`, and in my new (nearly blank) project I have in my `main.js` following code:

```
console.log("Hello world");
PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');
```

On the JavaScript console I got this error:

> PlayersList.insert({
>   name: "David",
>   score: 0
>   });
>   "YEK8N2KYHH2YeeHTr"
>   debug.js:41 insert failed: Method '/players/insert' not found

Please help!

Comment: I wish this code to run on both  server and client

Answer (score 1):

As you are using it at the client side, you can do it like:

```
PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection(null);
PlayersList.insert({ name: "David", score: 0 });
```

[image]

Comment: Im running through a meteor tutorial, and /i think need to use the db in the server as well, thus i must give it a name in my main.js as i did. how can i get it to work not only clientside?

Comment: You can do it by writing the code at Meteor.isServer() {}. By this your collection will be created at the server, as it is more secure to create collection at server.